# How do you know where to dig for insects underground?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How do you know where to dig for insects underground?  I have searched all over when I hear the chirping, but no luck finding the insects.

Comment: The only thing I know of is that hitting rocks with a shovel have a chance of producing bugs, same thing with walking close to or shaking a tree.  I've read that bugs can just be found by digging but I've never been able to do that successfully.  +1 I'm interested in finding out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only bug that's underground is a **mole cricket** and are extremely hard to find and catch.

You just have to dig in the area where the *sound* is until you find it.

Once you've dug it up it tries to make an escape so be prepared to switch to your net to catch it. You'll have a better success rate if you're not near a tree or rock as that's where they run to for cover.

One **method** people use is to dig a hole and if nothing is there, re-fill it and plant a flower there to mark where you've previously dug. This also stops the insect moving into that square; narrowing the possible squares it can be in.

**Also**, there's a possibility it's not an insect at all and is in fact a frog swimming in a pond or the river which maybe why you can't find it.

Comment: I never thought of marking the dug up spots. I will try that and see what happens. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If a villager is in the area of the mole cricket, they'll look in the direction of the bug. They do that for anything that makes noise, though. So if you're by a pool of water and a villager is staring at the water, that's probably something in the water.

Comment: Oh yeh. I forgot to mention that. Well spotted! Got to love our villagers :) Helpful lil critters.